# Converting HTML file to PDF file in Iphone

Tags: iphone

This is my first thread iam developing an application in which i have to convert the HTML contents to pdf file.

I had generate the PDF File but don't know how to create a pdf file from HTML format.
Anyone can suggest the solution?

Thank You.

Comment: htm2pdf.co.uk has an API you can call over HTTP GET, if you pass the URL you'll receive the PDF in your IPhone app

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that's really what you want to do? It's not as if an iPhone application can't display HTML if that's what's needed...

You can use a UIWebView to render the HTML into a pdf file as a bitmap: see 
[this discussion (HTML to PDF conversion library?)](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/312778dbcc94cc1d).

Comment: I want to do it programmatically in iphone application. were there is an html string coming from server and i need to save that html in pdf file and store in local resources.