# Exporting annotated documents on the iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, xhtml

interesting question. I am about to build an iPad application that shows the user pages of text. This text is created as follows: original XML (from a MarkLogic server no-less...) and assets (mainly images) converted to XHTML and rendered in the objective-c native app for the user to view.

The user then annotates the content in two ways: highlights and makes notes. Both of these can be enabled via inserting some appropriate tags in the XHTML and rendering it correctly in the app. Not a problem so far.

However - now the user wants to export the annotated document as a file and send via email (not in XHTML format) as an attachment.

I want to enable the user to export to a common filetype (e.g. Odf, PDF, docx) that supports comments and highlights. This conversion of XHTML->??? must be done in the app.

Any ideas on the best format and how easily to achieve the transformation in the native app using objective-c code/libraries?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be an entirely satisfying answer, but hopefully it will get you started.

It seems like the handiest way to do this is to send the html document to a server, do the conversion on the server, and send resulting rendered pdf (or whatever document format you choose) back to the iphone.  If you take this route, the [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) library looks like a decent candidate, although I've never used it myself.

About five minutes of googling turned up some conversations about folks who were trying to the html -> pdf conversion on the device itself, but in my very brief reading, I didn't find anything promising.  Here are some starting points:

- [Converting HTML file to PDF file in Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453915/converting-html-file-to-pdf-file-in-iphone)
- http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/312778dbcc94cc1d?pli=1
- http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/10989-pdf-creation-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for this - much appreciated. My back-up plan was along those lines of using an ec2 instance or something to render remotely. I was hoping for something on the device though...